# Why do methods accepting Foo<Parent> not take Foo<Child> but methods accepting Parent take Child?

Tags: java, generics

*(First, I apologize if some of this phrasing is awful, I'm not sure what to call some of these things, leave a comment if you have a better idea and I can edit.)*

Today I ran into an issue like below in Example1. If you have a generic that is declared as having a child of the generic's allowed types (`Foo<Bazz> foo = new Foo<Bazz>();`) it will make a compile-time error if you give it to a method that takes only the generic's parent type (`method1(Foo<Bar> foo)`).

```
public class Example1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<Bazz> foo = new Foo<Bazz>();
        method1(foo); // Compilation error below
    }

    public static void method1(Foo<Bar> foo) {
    {}

    public static class Foo<B extends Bar>
    {}

    public static class Bar
    {}

    public static class Bazz extends Bar
    {}
}
```

> **Error:** The method `method1(Example1.Foo<Example1.Bar>)` in the type `Example1` is not applicable for the arguments `(Example1.Foo<Example1.Bazz>)`

**This is very odd to me, because the following works fine.** You can make some object that is a child type (`Child c = new Child();`) and methods that accept the parent (`method2(Parent p)`) will still accept it just fine.

```
public class Example2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
        method2(c);
    }

    public static void method2(Parent p)
    {}

    public static class Parent
    {}

    public static class Child extends Parent
    {}
}
```

**Why can I pass child types into parameters asking for parent types but not generics with child types into parameters asking for generics with parent types?**

I'm sure it's just some standard, but why? Is a `Foo<Bazz>` not a `Foo<Bar>` in a similar manner to a `Bazz` being a `Bar`?